# What is this beauty, seen here after a heavy landing?

Tags: aircraft-identification

A high-wing monoplane with a curved leading edge.

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether the front downward-projecting fin was intended to skid along the ground until take-off, or what-- that would seem awkward!

Comment: @quietflyer _"There was a small elevator mounted at the front of the fuselage as well as a **rectangular rudder mounted underneath, which also served as a nose skid**."_. I bet ground handling was _just swell_ :D

Comment: Oh! Those magnificent men in their flying machines!

Answer (score 35):

It is a [Blériot V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%A9riot_V). Only one was ever built and it did not fly very well. (if at all)

It was a canard configuration pusher monoplane so you are looking at it backwards. The curved part of the wing is the trailing edge, not the leading edge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While it's aesthetically pleasing the design makes my skin crawl and I wouldn't want to fly it. It looks unstable to me, just seeing how close the wheels are together is worrying. the rudder in the front means it will have very little directional control at low speeds.

Comment: All of those (to us) extremely wierd looking designs during this 'age' of flying (very late/very early 1800/1900's... wonder how many might have gone on to be usable if they didn't simply get discarded as ideas after the first crash?

Comment: Also, looking at the above photo.. can't hep but to wonder how it was supposed to actually take off, the props look like it can't nose-up without ground striking, even with those wheels....

Answer (score 29):

That is almost undoubtedly the [Blériot V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%A9riot_V)

> The Blériot V was an early French aircraft built by Louis Blériot in 1907 and was his first monoplane. Although Blériot only achieved a couple of short flights in it, the second resulting in a crash which damaged the aircraft beyond repair, it was the first of his experimental aircraft to achieve any measure of success.

[image]
<sub>Image [not subject to copyright](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bleriot_V.jpg)</sub>

Here is a slightly clearer image of your "crashed" instance
[image]
<sub>Source: https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/bleriot/imag-05.html</sub>

Comment: Many thanks to you all or taking the time to answer my question - much appreciated.